# Converting existing wp7 app to trial

Tags: windows-phone-7, trial

I have an existing free app in WP7 marketplace with fairly large user base.

If I convert it to trial and implement proper use of trial api, what version would existing users get - full or trial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existing users will get the full app, as they effectively purchased the app already for $0.

Answer (score -1):

as far as i know, user will get a trial version..
CMIIW